# Python sparql query on "wrong" URI's

Tags: python, sparql, dbpedia

I wrote a python script that goes through a list of URI's and runs the following query on each of them:

```
query = "SELECT ?subject WHERE {<http://dbpedia.org" + uri + "> dct:subject ?subject.}"
```

This works when the given URI is correct, such as 
`/resource/Android_TV`.

But in my list of URI's I also have other URI's such as `/resource/Sheldon_J._Plankton`.

When I run this query it doesn't find anything, but if I go to the corresponding DBPedia page `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Sheldon_J._Plankton`

it changes to

`http://dbpedia.org/page/Plankton_(character)`.

So apparantly the correct URI for this page would be:

`resource/Plankton_(character)`.

Is it possible to write the query in such a way that it changes the URI to be correct? This list of URI's is very, very long so I can't manually check and fix them unfortunately.

Comment: Wikipedia redirects are directly reflected by the DBpedia dataset. seee the answer below how redirects are modelled (`dbo:wikiPageRedirects`) in DBpedia and can be queried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can follow `<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageRedirects>`:

```
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Sheldon_J._Plankton> dbo:wikiPageRedirects*/dct:subject ?subject .
```

The `*` will make the property path match zero or more redirects.

Comment: And perhaps the OP needs `SELECT DISTINCT`.